# Duplicating SVG's

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an svg image that I want to duplicate n number of times on the screen. Each time I want to change its position (x and y). For example, I would like to use one svg to create a 3x3 square of the duplicated svg.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Use a <use> tag probably.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and what I did was

```
const duplicateHtml = (element, quantity) => {
const html = new Array(quantity)
.fill('')
.map(() => {
  return element.innerHTML;
})
   // joing all the elements and  returning a string
.join('');
  return (element.innerHTML = html);
};
duplicateHtml(document.querySelector('.svg-images'),3);
```